# Unable to access array from included file when using require_once

Tags: php, arrays, require, require-once, var-dump

My issue is that if I use require_once to include a file that has an array, I can't access that array from the file that's including it. For example this is my foo.php file

```
<?php
$array['name'] = 'John';
$array['age'] = 34;
?>
```

And this is my bar.php file

```
<?php
//if i use require here instead of require once, the var_dump returns true
require_once('foo.php');
//This would return null
var_dump($array);
?>
```

How can I go about finding the issue?

Comment: In your bar.php try a `var_dump(file_get_contents('foo.php'));` - this is just make sure that you're including the correct file, because from what you've posted, there shouldn't be an issue. I copy/pasted ran your exact code to see if there was something an initial eyes-only check missed, but it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue. The code runs fine with both require_one or require. You are doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I just got done fooling with this exact same problem. Here was my original setup that I was experiencing the issue with.

```
<?php
require_once('SiteProcesses.class.php');
$login = new SiteProcess();

$login->testForLogin();

require_once('header.php');
require_once('settings.php'); # This is where the array was set

var_dump($array);
?>
```

And of course the output was:

```
NULL
```

Just a little more information:

I was including the '***settings.php***' file in both the '***testForLogin()***' method AND the '***header.php***' file. I finally got the array to work correctly with THIS configuration:

```
<?php
require_once('settings.php'); # This is where the array was set

require_once('SiteProcesses.class.php');
$login = new SiteProcess();

$login->testForLogin();

require_once('header.php');

var_dump($array);
?>
```

And now the script is working correctly.

```
array(2) { [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "2" }
```

So apparently something was going wrong trying to call the array from the settings file after including the settings file after all the other files were included. Just putting the settings file as the first included file worked for me.

***Names have been changed to protect the innocent*

***Yes, I understand that some of you who happen upon this post may have a different way of doing the same thing and of course you think that your way is better. Yada yada. Please keep your opinions to yourself. If I want a different way of doing it then I'll go looking for it. I don't need you to inject YOUR unwelcomed way in MY post. Thank you.*